# Добавление элементов в начало списка

Tags: python

Есть 2 списка

```
in1 = [23,55,0]
in2 = [100]
```

Нужно во второй список добавить в начало списка столько нулей, чтобы количество элементов в обоих списках стало одинаковым. К сожалению, стандартная библиотека дает возможность добавлять элементы только в конец.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"стандартная библиотека дает возможность добавлять элементы только в конец" - это не так. list.insert() позволяет добавлять элементы в произвольные позиции.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того, чтобы изменять существующий список, можно создать новый:

```
In [5]: in1 = [23,55,0]

In [6]: in2 = [100]

In [7]: [0] * (len(in1) - len(in2)) + in2
Out[7]: [0, 0, 100]
```

А потом уже присвоить его в `in2`, если потребуется

Comment: Было бы неплохо аргументировать downvote.